# How to work with the new channel forms and the new grid fieldtype ( and updateing it)

Tags: channel-form, grid

My little test looks like blow (fecthing a static channel entry 2 - works getting the data out )

When I submit my grid fields gets empty'ed Can somebody please help with the right syntax to update the grid values - plus if I want to add a new row.

my grid field is called mylist , in this i have two textfields text3 and date4

How is it done ??

{couldn't get the code to display so attact a image}
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use

```
{field:your_grid_fieldname}
```

to automatically output the grid content. Make sure you are also including the channel form css:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: Had the idea to only show some fields
( Guess i can start hiding Stuff in CSS ), 
But your solution works thanks (thumbs up).

Comment: I believe you can also do it like you were originally trying to, but the input name has to be correct for each cell. Take a look at the html source when using the {field:your_name} tag and you can see the format that ee is expecting for a grid cell. It'll be something like name="testgrid[rows][row_id_2][col_id_8]".

Comment: I see what you mean . Thanks very helpful .

Comment: I also wish there were more options for customizing the output. In my case, the autogenerated table is mysteriously wide and I can't seem to control it, and the row handles don't work… :-/

Comment: I'm having same issue that Charlie is. Did anyone get this customized and working? If so how?