# Add/Edit Form in Custom Module

Tags: forms, module

Developing a form using custom module for members to update football match day statistics.  These include team sheets, goals substitutions.  I have been able to get the team sheets working grand but stuck on adding in the goal scorers. On my form I will have to have a row per goal, so if a team scores 1,2,X amount of goals in the game I will need the same amount of rows. The data to be saved will be player, time of goal and whether a penalty or not.

I have a drop down list for the players name, textbox for time and a checkbox for penalty.

What I need help with is how to display the number of rows per goal. And I would also like use the same form for adding and editing the goals.

My module function

```
public function match_stats(){

    $match_id = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('match_id');
    $team_id = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('team_id');
    $match = ee()->clubmanager_matches->__get_match($match_id);
    $sql = "SELECT club_id FROM exp_ca_exec_clubs where member_id = ?";
    $query = ee()->db->query($sql, array(ee()->session->userdata('member_id')));

    $club_id = $query->row()->club_id;  
    $season_id = 16;

    // Build an array to hold the form's hidden fields
    $hidden_fields = array(
        "match_id" => $match_id,
        "club_id" => $club_id,
        "team_id" => $team_id,
        "season_id" => $season_id,
        "ACT" => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id( 'Clubmanager', 'match_team_action' ),
        "return" => ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('return')
    );

    // Build an array with the form data
    $form_data = array(
        // Send form back to this url - the action must be the same as the form
        "action" => ee()->functions->create_url( ee()->uri->uri_string ), 
        "id" => ee()->TMPL->form_id,
        "class" => 'form-horizontal',
        "hidden_fields" => $hidden_fields
    );

    // Make sure errors is actually an array
    if( ! is_array( self::$errors ) ) {
        self::$errors = array();
    }

    // Match Stats Goals
    $matchPlayersList = ee()->clubmanager_players->__get_match_players_list($team_id, $match_id);
    $clubplayerslist = ee()->clubmanager_players->__get_club_players_list($club_id,  $season_id);

    if($matchPlayersList > 0):
        $variables['players'] = $matchPlayersList;
    else:
        $variables['players'] = $clubplayerslist;
    endif;

    // Set up array to parse tagdata
    $variables['errors'] = array(
        array( self::$errors )// list of error messages
    );

    // Fetch contents of the tag pair, ie, the form contents
    $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;

    // Parse tagdata for errors/submitted values
    $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->parse_variables_row( $tagdata, $variables );

    // Create the form
    $form = ee()->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . 
        $tagdata . 
        "</form>";

    return $form;

}
```

My template code

```
{exp:clubmanager:match_stats 
                    match_id="{segment_3}"
                    team_id="{segment_4}"
                    return="clubhouse/fixtures/edit-success"
}
 <!--Table Search v1-->
                <div class="table-search-v1 margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Player Name</th>
                                    <th>Assist Player Name</th>
                                    <th>Goal Time</th>
                                    <th>Penalty</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>


                                      <select name="player_goal">
                                        <option value="0">Select Player</option>
                                        {players}
                                        <option value="{id}">{name}</option>
                                        {/players}
                                      </select>

                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <select name="player_assist">
                                        <option value="0">Select Player</option>
                                        {players}
                                        <option value="{id}">{name}</option>
                                        {/players}
                                      </select>
                                    </td>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                     <td>
                                      <input type="text" placeholder="time"     class="form-control" name="time" value="{time}"  />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <!--End Table Search v1-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a grid field type, and programatically set the new rows on your template.

Ref :

- https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html
- https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#grid-fieldtype-development
- [Adding New Grid Entries With Channel:Form](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/adding-new-grid-entries-with-channelform/31240#31240)

Answer (score 0):

So after some head scratching I have came up with this as they way to do it.  There are going to be better ways to do this but this works for me at the moment. I have only included the main part of the code to build out the form tags.

```
// If no recorded goals fill out form with blank rows for score
    if($recorded_goals == 0){
        $num = 1;
        $goals = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $score; $i++){
            $goals[] = array('num' => $num++,
                             'row' => $i
                );
            }
        $variables['goals'] =  $goals ;
    }elseif($recorded_goal_count >= $score){// Display all recorded goals in the form.
                foreach ($recorded_goals as $row){
                    $i=0;
                    $num = 1;
                    $goals = array();
                    foreach ($recorded_goals as $goal)
                    {
                        $goals[] = array('num' => $num++,
                                         'row' => $i++,
                                         'goal_id' => $goal['goal_id'],
                                         'player_name' => $goal['player_name'], 
                                         'player_id' => $goal['player_id'],
                                         'assist_name' => $goal['assist_name'],
                                         'assist_id' => $goal['assist_id'],
                                         'goal_id' => $goal['goal_id'],
                                         'time' => $goal['time'],
                                         'penalty' => $goal['penalty']
                                        );
                    }
                    $variables['goals'] =  $goals ;
                }
    }elseif($recorded_goal_count < $score){//Not enough recorded goals fill form will data and blank rows.
        foreach ($recorded_goals as $row){
            $i=0;
            $num = 1;
            $goals = array();
                foreach ($recorded_goals as $goal)
                {
                    $goals[] = array('num' => $num++,
                                     'row' => $i++,
                                     'goal_id' => $goal['goal_id'],
                                     'player_name' => $goal['player_name'], 
                                     'player_id' => $goal['player_id'],
                                     'assist_name' => $goal['assist_name'],
                                     'assist_id' => $goal['assist_id'],
                                     'goal_id' => $goal['goal_id'],
                                     'time' => $goal['time'],
                                     'penalty' => $goal['penalty']
                                    );
                }
                $variables['goals'] =  $goals ;
                for ($i = $recorded_goal_count; $i < $score; $i++){
                    $goals[] = array('num' => $num++,
                                    'row' => $i
                        );
                }
            $variables['goals'] =  $goals ;
        }
    }
```

Template code to process the form

```
 {exp:clubmanager:match_stats 
                    match_id="{segment_3}"
                    team_id="{segment_4}"
                    return="clubhouse/fixtures/edit-success"
                }
  <!--Table Search v1-->
                <div class="table-search-v1 margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Player Name</th>
                                    <th>Assist Player Name</th>
                                    <th>Goal Time</th>
                                    <th>Penalty</th>
                                    <th>Delete?</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {goals}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    {num}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="goals[{row}][goal_id]" value="{goal_id}" />
                                    <select name="goals[{row}][player_id]">
                                        <option value="0">Select Player</option>
                                        {players}
                                        <option value="{id}" {if id == player_id}selected{/if}>{name}</option>
                                        {/players}
                                      </select>

                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <select name="goals[{row}][assist]">
                                        <option value="0">Select Player</option>
                                        {players}
                                        <option value="{id}" {if id == assist_id}selected{/if}>{name}</option>
                                        {/players}
                                      </select>
                                    </td>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                     <td>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="time" class="form-control" name="goals[{row}][time]" value="{if time}{time}{/if}"  />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                          <select name="goals[{row}][penalty]" class="form-control">
                                        {exp:low_variables:options var="lv_penalty"}
                                                <option value="{lv_penalty:data}" {if penalty == lv_penalty:data}selected{/if}>{lv_penalty:data_label}</option>
                                        {/exp:low_variables:options}
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="goals[{row}][delete]" value="delete_goal"  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {/goals}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <!--End Table Search v1-->
{/exp:clubmanager:match_stats}
```